# Vertical line below rotated text

Tags: css, css-transforms, pseudo-element

I wanted to have a vertical line below a rotated text, but the behaviour I am attaining with my code is that the line starts at the center of the text.

```css
.email {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  position: fixed;
  left: 3rem;
  bottom: 10rem;
}

.email a {
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 1rem;
}

.email::after {
  content: "";
  width: 1px;
  height: 5rem;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="email">
  <a href="#">test@mail.com</a>
</div>
```

Following is an image of my actual output:
[image]

How can I have the line below the rotated text?

Comment: Could you make this into a working Snippet to illustrate the issue?

Comment: It works in if you click expand snippet. Some weird behaviour going on with the snippet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add `transform: rotate(90deg);` also to the pseudo-element (and maybe also add some `margin` to create a bit of a distance to the text.

```css
.email {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  position: fixed;
  left: 3rem;
  bottom: 10rem;
}

.email a {
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 1rem;
}

.email::after {
  content: "";
  width: 1px;
  height: 5rem;
  background: red;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  margin-top: 0.5rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="email">
  <a href="#">test@mail.com</a>
</div>
```

(Note: Use `full page` mode to view the example, otherwise you won't see the text.)

Comment: I actually wanted the line vertical, but the margin-top was what I was missing. Adding a margin of about 8rem shifts the line to the right place. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

`writing-mode: vertical-rl;` you can achieve this. for more information visit [this.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/writing-mode)

```css
:root {
  --height-for-line: 60px;
}

.email {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
}

.email a {
  color: white;
  text-transform: none;
  writing-mode: vertical-rl;
  background-color: blue;
  padding: 12px;
  position: relative;
}

.email a::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  height: calc(var(--height-for-line) - 15px);
  width: 2px;
  bottom: 5px;
  right: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="email">
  <a href="#">test@mail.com</a>
</div>
```

Comment: I achieved the desired outcome with @Johannes's solution but was having some trouble with the positioning. The `right` property assumes the width of the original text and not the rotated one. Your suggestion about `writing-mode: vertical-rl` worked wonders. Thank you.

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not find your answer to be more accurate for the question I posed. It just happened that a following issue that arose was fixable using the writing-mode.

Answer (score 0):

**Border as pseudo element. (the one you tried in question post)**

(I would suggest using the `text-decoration` or `border-bottom` solution under this code snippet.)

```css
.email {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  position: fixed;
  left: 3rem;
  bottom: 10rem;
}

.email a {
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 1rem;
}

.email::after {
  content: "";
  width: 1px;
  height: 6.2rem;
  background: red;
  transform: translateY(-60%);
  margin-right: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="email">
 <a href="#">test@mail.com</a>
</div>
```

**Solution with `text-decoration: underline;`**

```css
.email {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  position: fixed;
  left: 3rem;
  bottom: 10rem;
}

.email a {
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 1rem;
  text-decoration: underline;
  -webkit-text-decoration-color: red; /* Safari */  
  text-decoration-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="email">
 <a href="#"><u>test@mail.com</u></a>
</div>
```

**Solution using `border-bottom`**

```css
.email {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  position: fixed;
  left: 3rem;
  bottom: 10rem;
}

.email a {
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 1rem;
  border-bottom: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="email">
 <a href="#"><u>test@mail.com</u></a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

> I wanted to have a vertical line below a rotated text

I've shifted things around for you a little:

- I've applied the `::after` pseudo-element to the `<a>` element
- I've swapped dimensions of the  `::after` pseudo-element so that it represents a horizontal (rather than a vertical) line
- I've applied `transform: rotate(90deg);` to `.email` (rather than `.email a`)

---

**Working Example**

```css
.email {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 3em;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  transform-origin: 0 0;
}

.email a {
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 1rem;
}

.email a::after {
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  width: 5rem;
  height: 1px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="email">
  <a href="#">test@mail.com</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a pseudo, you could use `box-shadow`

(inset to work better with transform)

```css
.email {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  position: fixed;
  left: 3rem;
  bottom: 10rem;
}

.email a {
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 1rem;
  box-shadow: inset 0 -1px 0 0 red;
  padding-bottom: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="email">
  <a href="#">test@mail.com</a>
</div>
```